# How do I increment automatically a variable when calling a Cypress method?

Tags: javascript, cypress, auto-increment

**createUserPatch** is an API custom command to create a new User.

You can see that I have created a variable "**A**"  inside it.

The variable is used in the body emails part `[a]+'freddie.doe@example.com','type': 'work','primary': true}]`

I want to find a way to automatically increase the variable "**A**" whenever I call the command createUserPatch.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('createUserPatch', (user) => {
    var A = 1;
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url:  '/scim/v2/users',
        qs: {
            key : Cypress.env('apiKey')                         
        }, 
        body :{
            schemas: user.schemas,
            userName: user.userName,
            emails: [{ 'value': [A]+'freddie.doe@example.com','type': 'work','primary': true}],
            name : 'Maurice'
        }   
    }).then(res => {
        return res.body;
    });        
});
```

I use this command in the test below in a before each.

```
let user = {
    schemas:'["urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"]',
    userName: 'John',
    userId: null,
    groupID: null 
};

describe('Deactivating a user ', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {        
        
        cy.createUserPatch(user).then((newUser) => {
            return user.userId = newUser.id;
        });
    });
....
```

Each time I run this test.
I want the value of the email to be increased.

First test -> 0freddie.doe@example.com

Second test -> 1freddie.doe@example.com

Third test -> 2freddie.doe@example.com

etc...

Comment: did you try without making it an array?

Comment: I tried making it without an array and it did work once. But if I run it second time it does not work.

Comment: adding an array won't fix it, var A = 1; is reset on each call, try putting it outside the definition then change `[A]+` to `(A++)+`

Comment: I changed it to (A++)+ and it does not change anything. I receive a 409 error saying that this email address is already used.

Comment: How are you using the `createUserPatch  `in your tests. Can you post that as well ?

Comment: I come to put it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress clears variables between tests, but a few ways to preserve data have been suggested in other questions (e.g write data to file).

Since you already use `Cypress.env(name)` to access environment variables you could use `Cypress.env(name, value)` to track the prefix.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('createUserPatch', (user) => {

  let prefix = Cypress.env('emailprefix') || 0;  // first time it may be undefined
                                                 // so "|| 0" initializes it
  Cypress.env('emailprefix', ++prefix);          // increment and save 

  cy.request({
    ...
    emails: [{ 'value': prefix+'freddie.doe@example.com','type': 'work','primary': true}],
```

Note, the prefix value will be preserved between runs, which may or may not be what you want.

To clear it between runs, add a `before()` which resets the value

```
before(() => Cypress.env('emailprefix', 0) );

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.createUserPatch().then(console.log)
})
```